# _updateCacheParams is not a function

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a nest route for goals which is setup as such:

```
this.resource('clients', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('client', { path: '/:id' }, function() {
      this.route('profile');
      this.route('sessions');
      this.route('payments');
      this.route('goals', function() {
        this.route('show', {path: '/:id' });
        this.route('new');
      });
      this.route('messages');
    });     
});
```

Going to the index route of Goals works fine where I have a defined `goals.hbs` and `goals/index.hbs` templates but only a `goals.js` controller. You can see this setup from the Ember inspector here:

[image: index route]

The problems, however, show up if:

- I add a explicit `goals/index.js` controller rather than relying on the auto-generated one
- I navigate to the "clients.client.goals.new" or "clients.client.goals.show" routes.

In all cases the error is effectively the same. In order to be explicit, let's take the case where there is *not* a `goals/index.js` controller but I navigate to 
"clients.client.goals.new". In this case I get the following error:

> Error while processing route: clients.client.goals.new controller._updateCacheParams is not a function TypeError: controller._updateCacheParams is not a function

[image: error message]

Very odd, I'm doing nothing fancy here. Really don't understand why I'd get this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: btw, this issue on github seems to be related but unfortunately it wasn't enough information to get me out of the hole I'm in: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `GoalsIndexRoute`. Internally ember generates the route if the controller is generated too, however if you define the controller and not the route you'll get this issue.

I had defined the `PostsNewController` but not the `PostsNewRoute` and adding the `PostsNewRoute` seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Sorry I never marked this and enough time has gone by I can't be 100% certain this is what fixed it but my recollection is that this WAS what fixed it so I'll mark it correct.